# while executing transaction on Bitfinity Testnet RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error

Tags: solidity, metamask, dapps, testnets, meta-transactions

**The error**

```
VM278:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error.
```

{code: -32603, message: 'Internal JSON-RPC error.', data: {…}}
code
:
-32603
data
:
{code: -32015, message: 'internal error: the search range exceeds the limit of 10000 blocks', cause: null}
message
:
"Internal JSON-RPC error."

**Getting this error when I trying to fetch data form blockchain using bitfinity blockchain.**

```
const filter =  marketplace.filters.Bought(null,null,null,null,null,account)
  
  const results = await marketplace.queryFilter(filter)

  
  const purchases = await Promise.all(results.map(async i => {
    // fetch arguments from each result
    i = i.args
    // get uri url from nft contract
    const uri = await nft.tokenURI(i.tokenId)
    // use uri to fetch the nft metadata stored on ipfs 
  
    const response = await fetch(uri)
    
    const metadata = await response.json()
    // get total price of item (item price + fee)
    console.log(metadata);
    const totalPrice = await marketplace.getTotalPrice(i.itemId)
    // define listed item object
    let purchasedItem = {
      totalPrice,
      price: i.price,
      itemId: i.itemId,
      name: metadata.name,
      description: metadata.description,
      image: metadata.image
    }
    return purchasedItem
  }))
```

Here is my solidity event

```
 event Bought(
    uint itemId,
    address indexed nft,
    uint tokenId,
    uint price,
    address indexed seller,
    address indexed buyer
);
```